# How to properly sign cordova app?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, signing

```
ERROR ITMS-90174: "Missing Provisioning Profile - Apps must contain a provisioning profile in a file named embedded.mobileprovision."
```

This issue has been plaguing me for the last 3-4 days, I have tried resigning and I am using a build config that looks like this:

```
{
    "ios": {
        "debug": {
            "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
            "provisioningProfile":"ID found in myapp.mobileprovision",
            "developmentTeam": "VKUC8843LP",
            "packageType": "development"
        },
        "release": {
            "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
            "provisioningProfile":"ID found in myapp.mobileprovision",
            "developmentTeam": "VKUC8843LP",
            "packageType": "app-store"
        }
    }
}
```

I am using cordova and here's the commands I am running to build the app:

```
cordova build ios --release --buildConfig
cd platforms/ios
pushd "build"
mkdir ./Payload
cp -R "emulator/myapp.app" ./Payload
zip -qyr MyApp.ipa ./Payload
rm -r ./Payload
popd
```

Then I put it in the ApplicationLoader and everytime I send it off, I get the above message. I have a build.json inside /App (directory before www). When I open the XCode file and checking to sign it says:

```
Provisioning profile "myapp" doesn't include signing certificate "iPhone Distribution: DEv Name(MYID1234)".
```

Comment: I've been getting this too after updating to xcode 10. Did you ever get a fix for this?

Comment: I now open up the xcode project in the platforms/ios and then do build - >archive it. I'll edit this later with better info.

Comment: I'm also getting this error since xcode 10 with cordova. I've always been going through xcode.

Answer (score 6):

This is a problem with the new XCode 10 build system, which Cordova is not (yet) compatible with.  Previous versions of XCode were opt-in for the new build system, but as of XCode 10 it's opt out.

If you're using XCode to do your build, then just go to File > Workspace Settings and select "Legacy Build".

Here are more details from the Cordova team: https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/407